# Хранение состояние ToggleSwitch. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть форма с `ToggleSwitch` (13 штук на форме) которые отвечают за настройки. У каждого есть свой Tag.
Пример такой формы

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <StackPanel>
        <ui:ToggleSwitch Content="1" Tag="1" />
        <ui:ToggleSwitch Content="2" Tag="2" />
        <ui:ToggleSwitch Content="3" Tag="3" />
        <ui:ToggleSwitch Content="4" Tag="4" />
        <ui:ToggleSwitch Content="5" Tag="5" />
        <ui:ToggleSwitch Content="6" Tag="6" />
        <ui:ToggleSwitch Content="7" Tag="7" />
        <ui:ToggleSwitch Content="8" Tag="8" />
        <ui:ToggleSwitch Content="9" Tag="9" />
        <ui:ToggleSwitch Content="10" Tag="10" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Мне нужно как-то получить состояние каждого `ToggleSwitch` в DataContext и определять что какой-то из `ToggleSwitch` изменил значение (True/False) для вывода кнопки "Применить". Изначальное состояние каждого `ToggleSwitch` получаю из json файла. В своем проекте использую `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm`

Comment: Из какой библиотеки ToggleSwitch? Какой у него неймспейс? Покажите код, как вы устанавливаете значение контрола. Не вижу биндингов.

Comment: ToggleSwitch из https://github.com/lepoco/wpfui , binding'ов нету так как в этом вся суть вопроса. Я конечно могу сделать под каждый ToggleSwitch переменную и привязывать её, но может есть другое решение ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создаете модель данных для свича

```
public class ToggleModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string title;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool isChecked;
}
```

Создаете коллекцию

```
[ObservableProperty]
private ObservableCollection<ToggleModel> toggleItems;
```

Заполняете её, и просто привязываетесь

```xml
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ToggleItems}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ToggleModel}">
                <ui:ToggleSwitch Content="{Binding Title}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Собственно готово.

```
ToggleItems = new();
ToggleItems.Add(new ToggleModel { Title = "Test", IsChecked = true });
```

Далее можно просто обращаться к коллекции и считывать или програмно изменять состояние элементов, например.

```
bool isTestChecked = ToggleItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title == "Test").IsChecked;
```

Comment: А ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ToggleItems}" это по сути лист, я верно понимаю ?

Comment: @Ask0n `ObservableCollection<ToggleModel>` же, и да, она по поведению похожа на `List<T>`.

Comment: Еще 1 вопрос, а как лучше всего отслеживать изменение этих самых ToggleSwitch. Например пользователь изменил 4 штуки ToggleSwitch и ему вывелась кнопка примень, а потом 1 ToggleSwitch вернул в изначальное состояние, но кнопка осталась. Знаю что у ```ObservableCollection``` есть Event на изменение, но что-то мне подсказывает, что так не выйдет.

Comment: @Ask0n Почитайте документацию `[ObservableProperty]` вы же выбрали этот тулкит, значит готовы с ним работать. Там вроде можно добавить метод, котрый будет вызваться при изменении свойства. Событие `CollectionChanged` самой коллекции - это измение состава коллекции, и к изменениям внутри её элементов оно не имеет никакого отношения. Если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его отдельно, комментарии для этого не предназначены.

Comment: @Ask0n можете посмотреть этот пример https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData.Samplz